# Kafkaconsumer is not safe for multi-threading access

Tags: spark-streaming

I am using below code to read from Kafka topic , and process the data.

```
JavaDStream<Row> transformedMessages = messages.flatMap(record -> processData(record))
                .transform(new Function<JavaRDD<Row>, JavaRDD<Row>>() {
                    //JavaRDD<Row> records = ss.emptyDataFrame().toJavaRDD();
                    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

                    public JavaRDD<Row> call(JavaRDD<Row> rdd) throws Exception {
                        records = rdd.union(records);
                        return rdd;
                    }
        });

       transformedMessages.foreachRDD(record -> {
            //System.out.println("Aman" +record.count());
            StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

            Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(records, schema);
            ds.createOrReplaceTempView("trades");
            System.out.println(ds.count());
            ds.show();

        });
```

While running the code, i am getting below exception :

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1624)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1197)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
```

The fact that i only have one DStream, i am not sure why i am getting this exception.
I am reading from 3 partitions in a Kafka topic. I assume that the "createDirectStream" will be creating 3 consumers to read the data.

Below is the code for for KafkaConsumer, acquire method:

```
 private void acquire() {
        this.ensureNotClosed();
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        if(threadId != this.currentThread.get() && !this.currentThread.compareAndSet(-1L, threadId)) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException("KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access");
        } else {
            this.refcount.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is weird. Are you running local or a cluster? If cluster, what kind? Could you add the code where the stream is created and the implementation of `processData` ?

Comment: It seems it's a nasty bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19185

Comment: I am running on local, but the Kafka topic is centralized. The "processData" method is just deserializing the messages that we get in the stream.
As per my understanding, one consumer reads from one kafka partition. In this case, either multiple consumers are accessing the same kafka partition, or the consumers are getting shuffled.

Comment: Checkout last part of my post, i just edited it.
I am thinking, is there any configuration that i can make to stop this.

Answer (score 9):

Spark 2.2.0 has a workaround using no cache.
Just use spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled to `false`.
Take a look on this [pull](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18234) request

Comment: Note that this has to be set on the SparkConf (passed to the SparkSession builder).

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem of [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265714/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-kafkaconsumer-is-not-safe-for-multi-t) , you have more than one thread running with the same consumer and Kafka does not support multithreading. Also make sure you are not using spark.speculation=true as it will cause the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

As described in this bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19185, it's a known issue with Spark/Kafka.

In my case, I am going to avoid using window, and use partitioning in combination with batchInterval and blockInterval, as described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#level-of-parallelism-in-data-receiving

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code, you perform two actions on RDD

```
 transformedMessages.foreachRDD(record -> {
        //System.out.println("Aman" +record.count());
        StructType schema = 
        DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

        Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(records, schema);
        ds.createOrReplaceTempView("trades");

        System.out.println(ds.count());
        ds.show();

    });
```

Two consumers from Consumer Group tried to read the Kafka topic partition, but Kafka allows only one consumer from one consumer group can read the Kafka topic partition. The solution for this issue is: cache the RDD

```
 transformedMessages.foreachRDD(record -> {
        //System.out.println("Aman" +record.count());
        StructType schema = 
        DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

        Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(records, schema);
        ds.cache()

        System.out.println(ds.count());
        ds.show();

    });
```