# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a `Scala` `Spark Streaming` application that receives data from the same topic from 3 different `Kafka producers`.

The Spark streaming application is on machine with host `0.0.0.179`, the Kafka server is on machine with host `0.0.0.178`, the `Kafka producers` are on machines, `0.0.0.180`, `0.0.0.181`, `0.0.0.182`.

When I try to run the `Spark Streaming` application got below error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 1 times,
>   most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 19.0 (TID 19, localhost):
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe
>   for multi-threaded access at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1625)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1198)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
>   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409) at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409) at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1204)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1203)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1203)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1325)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1211)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1190)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85) at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Now I read thousand of different posts but no one seems to be able to find a solution at this issue.

How can I handle this on my application? Do I have to modify some parameters on Kakfa (at the moment the `num.partition` parameter is set to 1)?

Following is the code of my application :

```
// Create the context with a 5 second batch size
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkScript").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true").set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "3").setMaster("local[4]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))

case class Thema(name: String, metadata: String)
case class Tempo(unit: String, count: Int, metadata: String)
case class Spatio(unit: String, metadata: String)
case class Stt(spatial: Spatio, temporal: Tempo, thematic: Thema)
case class Location(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, name: String)

case class Datas1(location : Location, timestamp : String, windspeed : Double, direction: String, strenght : String)
case class Sensors1(sensor_name: String, start_date: String, end_date: String, data1: Datas1, stt: Stt)    


val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "0.0.0.178:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "group.id" -> "test_luca",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics1 = Array("topics1")

  val s1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics1, kafkaParams)).map(record => {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    parse(record.value).extract[Sensors1]
  } 
  )      
  s1.print()
  s1.saveAsTextFiles("results/", "")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I've posted the stack trace of the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
s1.print()
s1.saveAsTextFiles("results/", "")
```

Since Spark creates a graph of flows, and you define two flows here:

```
Read from Kafka -> Print to console
Read from Kafka -> Save to text file
```

Spark will attempt to concurrently run both of these graphs, since they are independent of each other. Since Kafka uses a cached consumer approach, it is effectively trying to use the same consumer for both stream executions.

What you can do is cache the `DStream` before running the two queries:

```
val dataFromKafka = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics1, kafkaParams)).map(/* stuff */)

val cachedStream = dataFromKafka.cache()
cachedStream.print()
cachedStream.saveAsTextFiles("results/", "")
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps in part. I removed the print but i kept the cache. I've also reduced the size of the ``StreamingContext`` batch.

Comment: @lu_ferra If you don't need multiple iterations, don't cache, it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Using cache worked for me . In my case print , transformation and then print on  JavaPairDstream was giving me that error .
I used cache just before first print, it worked for me.

```
s1.print()
s1.saveAsTextFiles("results/", "")
```

Below code will work, i used similar code .

```
s1.cache();
s1.print();
s1.saveAsTextFiles("results/", "");
```